# My Nissan Pathfinder 2007 cental locking system works fine . But both rear doors wont open from the outside

Tags: nissan, central-locking, pathfinder

My Nissan Pathfinder 2007 central locking works.  But the rear doors won't open from the outside once unlocked.

Comment: If the door won't open from the outside, what makes you believe that it's been unlocked? Will it open from the inside? Have you taken the door card off to confirm that the exterior handles are still connected to the door latch?